# WP All Import | How can I set featured products with xpath?

Tags: xml, wordpress, xpath, woocommerce, wpallimport

I'm using wpallimport to import my products from xml file link, the files has a field named "reward" which indicates how much money I make from selling the products, so for example, I want products that have the "reward" value more than "x" to be featured .. how is that possible in code?

Thanks in advance

Kindly check attached screenshots

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 0):

Does my product have a reward value superior to X ? Just write :

```
//reward>45
```

to get a boolean output (`TRUE/FALSE`) where 45 is the value you want to check.

If you need to return the products with a reward value superior to 45, write :

```
//product[reward>45]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it didn't work, as the plugin indicates "The value of presented xpath should be one of the following: ('yes', 'no')" .. not true or false .. I would really appreciate it If you can help me in this one.

Comment: Since no elements from your XML contain a 'yes' or 'no' statement, I think you're stuck... You should transform the `reward` element of your XML (with `xmlstarlet` or similar tool)  before importing it with WP All Import. Or develop your  own import function with PHP. https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/overview/